# get the first and second highest values of an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, max

I am trying to perform the following code:

```
function oldestAges(ages){
    if (ages == []){
      return [0,0]; 
    }else{
      var max = Math.max.apply(null, ages); 
              ages.splice(ages.indexOf(max), 1); 
      var max2 = Math.max.apply(null, ages); 
      return [max2,max];
  }
}
```

However, when testing [] as ages, the expected was '[0, 0]', instead got: '[-Infinity, -Infinity]'

Also, is there a much easier way to accomplish the same task? I ask because using R I could get the same result in much less number of lines. I am noob in javascript still.

Comment: You can't use `==` to compare arrays by their contents. The operator compares only by object identity, so one array will never ever be `==` to another array.

Comment: Use `if(ages.length == 0)` to test for an empty array.

Comment: The simple way is to sort the array and then return the first two elements.

Comment: As @Barmar implied: the problem is in this line: `if (ages == []){` - it will always return `false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple (not sure about the most optimal) way to achieve this:

```js
const input = [5, 150, 2, 8, 58, 4];

const result = input.sort((x, y) => y - x).slice(0, 2);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your array in descending order so that the first two elements contain the highest values.

```
ages.sort((a, b) => b - a);
```

Now `ages[0]` and `ages[1]` contain the two biggest numbers.

Answer (score 1):

`ages.length == 0` is what you can use to see if the number of the elements in the array is zero.

Your code has an error where you say `if (ages == [])`.

Try this,

```
function oldestAges(ages){
        if (ages.length == 0){
          return [0,0];
        }else{
          var max = Math.max.apply(null, ages);
                  ages.splice(ages.indexOf(max), 1);
          var max2 = Math.max.apply(null, ages);
          return [max2,max];
      }
    }
```